# Alterando border de input com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

O que há de errado? Preciso deste efeito para validar formulário.

```js
var input = document.getElementByClass("dado");
input.style.border = "1px solid red";
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando errado o [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). E o retorno é um array, portanto deve ser acessado pelo índice:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("dado");
input[0].style.border = "2px solid red";
```

```html
<input class="dado" />
```